Wideband Photodiode Amplifier (>= 50MHz) and Obnoxiously Big Input Bias Currents of Current Feedback Amplifiers
I'm toying with the idea of building a >50MHz Bandwidth Photodiode Amplifier, built around a 1GHz AD8009ARZ Current Feedback Amplifier. I got two photodiodes that have a bandwidth exceeding 1GHz.
The problem is that the AD8009 (the only CFA available to me with a big enough Bandwidth) has gigantic input currents, on the order of tens to hundreds of uA. To circumvent this issue I plan on using a buffer with 190MHz bandwidth (made out of a Voltage Feedback Amplifier) to buffer the output of the resistive readout of the photodiode .
The final circuit I have in mind looks something like this:

My questions are:

Would biasing the non-inverting input of a CFA as shown above be a viable option, or is there a need for a different type of biasing for the high current draw CFA?

Is the configuration used for the non-inverting amplifier viable for    Current Feedback Amplifiers?



If you're cap-coupling it anyway, and the source impedance is low, what difference does it make? -- have you compared to the unbuffered case?  In other words: you say your concern is DC bias current, but you haven't asserted proof that the stated concern is in fact a problem.

Where are the results of simulating your circuit. Surely this is the sensible next step?

@Andyaka I would simulate it if I had the correct spice model. I've only found a pspice .cir model and I have no idea how to convert that type of file format.

@TimWilliams I am perhaps a bit confused. What I wanted was to have a DC path for the input of the CFA (hence the input voltage divider) and also have only a small "error" current.

Error from, or with respect to, what? The voltage divider is a free variable; you can set the values almost arbitrarily, and C5 ensures that variation won't be compounded by voltage gain. Perhaps another angle will do: what are you using VOUT for? AC signal analysis (e.g. AGC, filtering, mixing, etc.)? Fixed (DC) thresholds / bit slicing? Adaptive thresholds? I would imagine most end uses are immune to DC offset, at least until clipping occurs; and this is true whether dealing with it in the analog or digital (post-ADC) domain.


The problem is that the AD8009 (the only CFA available to me with a big enough Bandwidth) has gigantic input currents, on the order of tens to hundreds of uA

Suppose you DC-servo the bottom end of the 50Ω source resistor to keep the average value of the amplified signal where you want it, e.g. mid-supply. That will allow you to DC-couple the thing.
With DC coupling, the bias currents flow into/out of the 50Ω source resistance. Their drift, from all sources, is much slower than signals of interest, and thus immaterial.
